# Is it a bug in jackson-datatype-jsr310 deserializer?

Tags: java, spring-data, jsr310

I know that's presumptuous to image found a bug in a library used every day by thousands of developpers. So I think the answer to my title question is "NO !!!", but ...

I have an object containing a date that I receive from my front end (JS), and I store it into a MongoDB database. I use Spring to get this object (with a REST Controller), and Spring to perform persistance (with a MongoDBRepository). My computer is configured with a CEST clock, so GMT+2 (UTC +0200).

The date in my POJO is stored in a LocalDateTime.

Here is my object :

```
class Test{
  LocalDateTime when;
  String data;
  // getter setters...
}
```

The following unit test show that Spring (which use jackson-jsr310) fill my LocalDateTime with an UTC Date Time.

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/test")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content("{\"when\":\"2017-03-31T14:20:28.000Z\",\"data\":\"toto\"}")).andExpect(status().isOk());

List<com.robopec.models.Test> tests =  testRepository.findAll();
Assert.assertEquals(14, tests.get(0).getWhen().getHour());
```

We can see in the jackson source code [LocalDateTimeDeserializer.java](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/LocalDateTimeDeserializer.java) line 74 :

```
 return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.parse(string), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

But when I save in my database, spring use spring-data-commons to convert my LocalDateTime to a Date before storing the date in the database. 
We can read in [spring-data-commons/../Jsr310Converters.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/convert/Jsr310Converters.java) this :

```
public static enum LocalDateTimeToDateConverter implements Converter<LocalDateTime, Date> {
        INSTANCE;
        @Override
        public Date convert(LocalDateTime source) {
            return source == null ? null : Date.from(source.atZone(systemDefault()).toInstant());
        }
    }
```

So, spring-data JSR310 Converters interpret a localdatetime as an instant in the default system zone.

The problem is that when my front end send "2017-04-03T20:00:00Z", the REST controller store it in a LocalDateTime with the following time : 20:00:00. And when the mongo-data converter convert it into a date, the resulting time is 20:00:00+0200 (because my computer is in CEST time zone).

My conclusion is that I shouldn't store my date in a LocalDateTime but rather in a Date (java.util) or in an Instant.

**But, is there a bug in one of the converters ?**

Comment: Are you using a LocalDateTime, or a LocalDate, as suggested by your POJO sample? What database are you using? Which release of Spring Data?

Comment: You are right, I am using a LocalDateTime (I will edit my post). Database is a MongoDB database. I use spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb version 1.5.1, and jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.6

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, the latest version of the Java driver for mongoDB still use java.util.Date to store dates, so using the Java 8 time api can be a bit of a hassle.

In one project I work on, I switched from Joda Datetime to the Java 8 time a few months ago. I couldn't get my way around with LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime and so on, so I decided to go with [Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) and it worked fine. Just remember to use the ISO8601 Zulu notation for your dates ("2017-03-31T14:20:28.000Z"), which is already what you're doing apparently.

Comment: This is also my conclusion.