# Mapping exception from Java 8 LocalDateTime to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, type-conversion, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, localdate

I appear to be having a problem writing a DB entity with a java.time.LocalDateTime field to a MongoDB table.  Everything I've read seems to say that this should not be a problem circa end-of-2014, but I'm still getting it for some reason:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.time.LocalDateTime] to type [java.util.Date]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174) ~[spring-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleWrite(MappingMongoConverter.java:849) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeSimpleInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:829) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeProperties(MappingMongoConverter.java:488) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:462) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:436) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:391) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:86) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.toDocument(MongoTemplate.java:1070) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doSave(MongoTemplate.java:1253) ~[spring-data-mongodb-2.0.8.RELEASE.jar:2.0.8.RELEASE]
...
```

I have a custom MongoConfig which looks like this.  I tried removing it but that didn't fix the problem, so the problem doesn't seem to be anything here, but nevertheless here it is:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfig {

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
private String database;

@Autowired
private MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory;

public @Bean
MongoDbFactory mongoDBFactory() {
    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), database);
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
    DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory);

    // Remove _class
    MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver, new MongoMappingContext());
    converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));

    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDBFactory(), converter);
}

}
```

I could write a custom converter to do this for me if I need to, but all the documentation I've read says this bug was fixed around November 2014 so I'm wondering what I've done wrong.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43201932/5873923. For storage, use Instant, and convert to/from LocalDateTime (or other classes from the time API) when needed.

Comment: You need to add a converter and register in spring.

Comment: I solved it by using the solution linked in @MarcTarin 's comment and just using java.time.Instant instead.

Comment: @Ertai87 don't hesitate to upvote the answer in the link I gave ;)